# Why can't I set object property to empty string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, undefined, string

I want to pass the values from my request body into a paramsDict object where I have defined constraint to test the parameters against. I don't require that all possible parameters are sent with every request and also, if a value is deleted on the client, it can be sent as an empty string.

So we pass the values to the dictionary like so

```
for ( p in paramsDict ) {
   if ( container[p] ) {
      paramsDict[p].value = container[p];
   }
  }
```

where container is set to req.body (in node.js express).

In the case where `container[p] = ""` the property `paramsDict[p].value` never gets set, i.e `typeof paramsDict[p].value` returns `"undefined"` (note: it does not exist on the object before I attempt to assign it here). This means adding an extra check which I would rather not have to:

```
if (typeof container[p] == "string" && container[p].length == 0){
  paramsDict[p].value = "";
}
```

Investigating I see that `paramsDict[p].value = ""` and `paramsDict[p].value = false` both set the property to the empty string and false respectively (I include false because the empty string is falsey in JS).

`typeof container[p]` returns `"string"` when the value is the empty string so I am very surprised that is does not assign the empty string as the value.

Is this a decision that has been made for this implementation of JS or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your check for the property [p] will return false even in the cases you care about (empty string or false).  Instead of `if (container[p])`, you should use `if (container.hasOwnProperty(p))`.

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question: empty string is falsy, so this will evaluate to false when `container[p] === ''`:

```
if ( container[p] ) {
```

So, assignment to `paramsDict` won't happen.

Comment: Of course! I was looking at the wrong part. Thanks.